# How to associate an event with a menuitem in WPF using VS2008?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, events, menuitem

I am in the process of learning WPF (I don't know much yet).  I know how to associate a menu subitem to an event by directly editing the xaml but, I'd like to know how to do the same thing using Visual Studio.

For instance, consider the following XAML snippet:

```xml
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock ="Top"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="White" BorderBrush ="Black">
       <MenuItem Header="_File"/>
       <Separator/>
       <MenuItem Header ="_Exit"
                 MouseEnter ="MouseEnterExitArea"
                 MouseLeave ="MouseLeaveArea"
                 Click ="FileExit_Click"/>
```

I'd like to be able to associate the "_Exit" menuitem with the appropriate event handlers for MouseEnter, MouseLeave and Click using Visual Studio instead of manually editing the xaml text.   I was trying to accomplish this by using the "Items" collection editor but, it seems to only allow editing of the subitem's properties and not the events.  Is there another editor/dialog/etc that allows editing the subitem's events ?

Thank you for your help,

John.

P.S: thank you H.B for taking the time to format the xaml properly. :-)

Comment: I've wondered this too, and haven't been able to find a way.  I don't think it's possible!

Comment: @Cory: hopefully one of the many experts that frequent this forum can confirm your suspicions (and mine as well by now.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not seem to be possible to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old thread but since I came across it, I figured someone else may benefit from a method that I found to use Visual Studio to view/edit the Event Handlers definitions of sub-MenuItems.

This method still requires that you access the XAML file but you do not have to edit it. Simply select (click) the record in the XAML file which defines the sub-MenuItem and you will be able to access the Events page in the Properties Window (F4).

If Microsoft is listening, I would say this is a design flaw (bug?) in the Collection Editor.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "edit with visual studio", so I hope I'm on the right track here...

You can give the items names in xaml:

```xml
<MenuItem Name="exitMenuItem" ....>
```

then in the c# codebehind:

```
exitMenuItem.Click += (s,e) =>
{
    DoIt(); // your event handling code
}
```

Comment: You can double-click on the root `MenuItem` in the WYSIWYG editor to generate a Click event for it.  He wants a way to do the same for child `MenuItem`s.  Not through editing XAML, but visually.

Comment: @H.B: you edited the xaml code I posted and it now looks much nicer.  How did you manage that ? (if I may ask)

Comment: @Hex440bx: See the [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Next time just paste the code, select it and press the code block button in the menus (curly braces) to indent it (which causes the brackets to be printed, also adds syntax highlighting, might not be the right language though, so there is a modifier for that)

Comment: @H.B: thank you.  I had already read the formatting help page but couldn't quite make it work the way it is supposed to.   I'll try again in my next post.  Hopefully, I'll get it right next time.

Answer (score 0):

on the Properties window for that item switch to the Events tab then double click on the box next to the event you want.

in 2008 I think that there is a button that looks like a lightning bolt that you can click to get the events. It should be in the same area as the buttons to sort alphabetically or to order by category or whatever.

Comment: correct me if I am wrong but, for menu subitems I could not get to an events page.  There is an events page for the menu "header" (such as "_File" in the example I gave) but there does not seem to be an event page for subitems (such as "_Exit" in the example I gave)

Comment: Looks like that is correct. Sorry I didn't check before posting.